# How to configure React-Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

So I have a context.

```
import React from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext({
  numberOfMeals: 0,
  meals: [],
});

export default CartContext;
```

I then import this into my App.JS

```
import React from "react";
import MealsBase from "./Components/Meals/MealsBase";
import CartContext from "./Context/CartContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ numberOfMeals: 0, meals: [] }}>
      <MealsBase/>
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I use this context within two components.

Component 1 :

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import "./CartIcon.css";
import CartContext from "../../Context/CartContext";

const CartIcon = () => {

  const cartContext = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button className="border">
        <h3>Your Cart : {cartContext.numberOfMeals}</h3>
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CartIcon;
```

Component 2 :

```
import React,{ useState, useContext } from "react";
import CartContext from "../../Context/CartContext";

const MealForm = () => {
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
    const mealContext = useContext(CartContext);

    const amountHandler = (event) => {
        setAmount(event.target.valueAsNumber);
    };

    const formHandler = (event) => {
        mealContext.numberOfMeals = mealContext.numberOfMeals + amount;
        console.log(mealContext.numberOfMeals);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={formHandler}>
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="number" step={1} min={-1} max={50} value={amount} onChange={amountHandler}/>
                <button type="submit"> + Add </button>
            </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default MealForm
```

The context seems to update in component two but not in component one.
I have an understanding that if useContexts values change then it causes a component to re-render. So I am struggling to understand why the CartIcon.js file is not being re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really updating the value the React way, you are mutating it. Move the context value into state and provide that out.

```
const CartContext = React.createContext({
  numberOfMeals: 0,
  setNumberOfMeals: () => {},
  meals: [],
  setMeals: () => {},
});
```

...

```
function App() {
  const [numberOfMeals, setNumberOfMeals] = useState(0);
  const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ numberOfMeals, setNumberOfMeals, meals, setMeals }}>
      <MealsBase/>
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

...

```
const MealForm = () => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
  const { setNumberOfMeals } = useContext(CartContext);

  const amountHandler = (event) => {
    setAmount(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  };

  const formHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNumberOfMeals(count => count + amount);
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={formHandler}>
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input type="number" step={1} min={-1} max={50} value={amount} onChange={amountHandler}/>
        <button type="submit"> + Add </button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank You I will try this! I am new to react so excuse the bad practises :D.                      
quick question off the back of that. Why doesn't the component CartIcon.js re-render when I do change the context value (I am presuming it doesn't because I am mutating it).

Comment: @SamirZafar Correct. React uses shallow equality checks, so if you mutate the state object instead of create a new state reference, React doesn't "see" that state was updated and doesn't rerender.